# Can Worklight Shell and Inner Applications be used to share common code across applications?

Tags: ibm-mobilefirst, code-sharing

My Worklight project contains two separate hybrid mobile applications. The applications have in common a good deal of HTML, CSS and JavaScript.  I need a way to encapsulate the common code so that it can be shared by both applications.

Can Worklight Shell and Inner Applications help me to share common code across applications?

If so, where can I find detailed documentation, example code or tutorials that use Shell and Inner Applications for this purpose?

If not, is there another way to share code across Worklight applications?

Answer (score 1):

Shell development in Worklight could potentially solve this for you, but its complexity is much greater and I am not convinced its price is worth it.
You can review shell development in the [Advanced Topics section](http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/mobile/worklight/getting-started.html#GS_advanced) of the [IBM Worklight Getting Started](http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/mobile/worklight/getting-started.html) web page.

Answer (score 1):

Yes you can reuse, you can add to Shell common CSS, Javascript functions, Plugins and they will be applied to all the project that are build on top of that.

If it is a hybrid app you can add CSS, JS, Images under `<<WLProject>>/components/<<ShellName>>/common`

For any plugins related to android or IOS you can add them into respective folders under `<<WLProject>>/components/<<ShellName>>`

Cheers !!